# arraylist is always created with a constant capacity

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to compute pascal's triangle given a row number. I am using recursion.

My code is below:

```
public static List<Integer> getRow(int rowIndex) {

      if (rowIndex == 1){
          List <Integer> list = new ArrayList(rowIndex+1);
          list.add(1);
          return list;
      }
        else{
              List<Integer> oldList = getRow(rowIndex -1);
              List <Integer> list = new ArrayList(rowIndex+1);
              int temp = 0;
              list.add(0,1);
              list.add(list.size()-1,1);
              System.out.println("rowIndex "+rowIndex);

              for (int i = 1; i < list.size()-1; i ++){
                 temp = oldList.get(i) + oldList.get(i-1);
                 list.add(i,temp);
              }
              return list;

        }
    }
```

It always returns [1,1] regardless of what row I am trying to get. I tried inserting print statements. I noticed the size of list is always 2 regardless of what rowIndex is.

```
 List <Integer> list = new ArrayList(rowIndex+1);
```

Is the line above not the correct way to create an ArrayList? Seems like my arraylist always has size = 2;

Comment: The ArrayList "capacity" is irrelevant, except for (supposed) performance tuning purposes.

Comment: When you do `list.add(0,1);` and then `list.add(list.size()-1,1);`, `list.size()` in the second statement is 1, so you're placing another "1" value into element 0 of the arraylist.

Comment: (`size()` returns the number of elements in the arraylist, not it's capacity.  You probably just want to use plain old `add(value)` rather than `add(index, value)`.)

Answer (score 2):

you misunderstand how `ArrayLists` do work and you really should [read the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

In short, the constructor's parameter defines the initial size of the ArrayList in memory, not the max size. If you instantiate a `new ArrayList<Integer>(2)`it only means that the jvm allocates upfront enough space for two Integers, and that when you add a third element then the jvm will grow the size of the ArrayList in order to allow you to add more elements.

Further, you can access an `ArrayList` position with `get()` only if an element has been added at this position.

Finally, keep in mind that `add` at a specific position shifts right all elements. Thus if you `add(10,1)` then `add(2,4)`, your first add will be shifted right.

Back to your question, if you absolutely want to use an `ArrayList` and not an `array`, you have to initialize your `ArrayList` with the right size, then `set` values at the right positions.

Here is a working solution :

```
// the method with your algorithm which has been slightly modified  
public static List<Integer> getRow(final int rowIndex) {
    // notice that I call a helper method which initialises correctly the ArrayList
    final List<Integer> list = init(rowIndex);
    if (rowIndex == 1) {
        // notice that I set the value at a given position
        // I can only do it because I initialised all values to 0 first
        list.set(0, 1);
    } else {
        final List<Integer> previousRowList = getRow(rowIndex - 1);
        // again, I set values...
        list.set(0, 1);
        list.set(rowIndex - 1, 1);
        for (int i = 1; i < (list.size() - 1); i++) {
            // set again...
            list.set(i, previousRowList.get(i - 1) + previousRowList.get(i));
        }
    }
    // lets print out the row
    System.err.println(list);
    // then return it
    return list;
}

public static List<Integer> init(final int size) {
    // passing the size is overkill, but well...
    final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
    // fill the ArrayList with zeros
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        list.add(i, 0);
    }
    // then return it
    return list;
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    getRow(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
}
```

If you run it you'll get a (not so nice, but working) Pascal's triangle. Here follows the result if you want 11 rows :

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
[1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1]
[1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]
[1, 10, 45, 120, 210, 252, 210, 120, 45, 10, 1]
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

I think you're miss-interpreting the data structures.

And array list is a LIST implemented on top of an array. Setting the size of the array in the constructor is a way to give control to the developer for the initial size of the array (This is rarely necessary as the class manages the array size itself--so just leave out this argument). So the size of an array list is actually the size of the list, which is the number of elements, not the number of buckets in the underlying array which is specified in the constructor.

If you know the size of the array you want, and you want to get and add at specific locations, use a standard array, not an array list.

However, I think your code will work if you move

```
list.add(list.size()-1,1);
```

to after your for-loop (I'm actually surprised it doesn't throw an index out of bounds exception). And since you're going left to right, none of your adds need an index specified, since it'll just add it to the end of the existing list.